# How to use the sed command in shell script

Tags: shell-script, sed

I want to replace the `<name>`, `<place>`, and `<address>` in my input file
(for example, `letter.txt`):

```
To : <name>
Address : <address>
Place : <place>
```

with the contents of a second file (`data.txt`):

```
johne 2334st. City
```

ao that the output be :

```
To : johne
Address : 2334st.
Place : City
```

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Crossposting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33724236/3776858

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
read -r n a p < data.txt
sed "s/<name>/$n/;s/<address>/$a/;s/<place>/$p/" letter.txt
```

Output:

```
To : johne
Address : 2334st.
Place : City
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" add sed's option `-i`.